# Windows8 Store app doesnt support onhashchange

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-8, dom-events

I am trying to make an WIN8 app out of my html5 project.
Unfortunately I have been using hashes and especially the event `onhashchange` which is not supported by Windows8 apps.

> This event is not supported for Windows Store apps built for Windows
>   using JavaScript.
>   [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I have been checking and apparently the event is emits a `{}` object when `onhashchange`

Is there any library or workaround to make the it pass the right event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to rewrite/adapt your code to use the `WinJS.Navigation` namespace. I guess that [`WinJS.Navigation.state`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229850.aspx) could be used instead of the hash. Then call `navigate` with the same URL and a different state.